# Dynamic Img Src URL within a DIV within Script using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to insert a dynamic url within a img src.

Below is my HTML and Script code. OnClick of a tab, I am calling a GET HTTP Method, which responds with image url. I want to use this image url with the img src field.

HTML Code

```
        ....
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="tm-tab-link" data-id="hot" onclick="isValid();" id="login">Reviews</a>
        </li>
        ...
        <div id="hot" class="tm-tab-content">
          <div class="tm-list">
              <div class="features_items" id="name"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        ....
```

Script -

```
$("#login").on("click", function isValid() {
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://xyz.foo.net/super",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
                
            var name = "";
            for(var i=0;i<=data.length-1;i++){
            name += '<div class="tm-list-item">' +
      
                // how to add the image url below DYNAMICALLY? 
                // how to insert data[i].img ?

              '<img src="??????????" id=image1 alt="Image" class="tm-list-item-img">' +  
                        '<div class="tm-black-bg tm-list-item-text">' +
                            '<h3 class="tm-list-item-name">' + data[i].name + '</h3>' +
                            '<p class="tm-list-item-description">' + data[i].review + '</p>' +       
                        '</div> ' +
                     '</div>' 
            }
            
            $("#name").html("");
            $("#name").append(name);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert("Refresh Page");
        }
    });

});
```

Sample JSON Response -

```
[
 {
  "name":"John",
  "review":"awesome product",
  "img":"https://img.com/cats"
  },
  {
  "name":"Shawn",
  "review":"good product",
  "img":"https://img.com/dogs"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- i just replace url with jsonplaceholder to test
- also , id must be unique that's not releated with your problem .

  $.ajax({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos",
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(data) {

  ```
        console.log(data);

        for(var i=0;i<=data.length-1;i++){
        name += '<div class="tm-list-item">' +


          '<img src="'+data[i].url+'"   id="image' + i + '" alt="Image" class="tm-list-item-img">' +  
                    '<div class="tm-black-bg tm-list-item-text">' +
                        '<h3 class="tm-list-item-name">' + data[i].name + '</h3>' +
                        '<p class="tm-list-item-description">' + data[i].review + '</p>' +       
                    '</div> ' +
                 '</div>' 
        }

        $("#name").html("");
        $("#name").append(name);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert("Refresh Page");
    }
  ```

  });

Comment: Good answer, and good observation about non-unique IDs. I took the liberty to turn your code into a snippet, and to slightly improve it by replacing `$("#name").html(""); $("#name").append(name);` with `$("#name").html(name);`

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks ( ` ) instead of simple quotes `'` or double quotes `"`. Backticks support string interpolation `${...}` and multiline :

```
name += `<div class="tm-list-item">
              <img src="${data[i].img}" id="image${i}" alt="Image" class="tm-list-item-img"/>
              <div class="tm-black-bg tm-list-item-text">
                    <h3 class="tm-list-item-name">${data[i].name}</h3>
                    <p class="tm-list-item-description">${data[i].review}</p>
               </div> 
        </div>`;
```

EDIT :

As @AmlKamel_ said, you can't have the same ID multiple times in your document. By adding `i` to it, you make unique IDs.